# C# Winforms DataSet update changes by partner id

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I have a `dataGridView` where I display the addresses of a certain partner by his ID. It does everything well! When I want to change, or add a new row to the grid, the data is successfully entered into the database, but the `partner_id` of the specific partner is not entered. In database `partner_id` is null.

**How do I define the partner id in this code of mine?**

The application logic uses multiple form layers and the database layer is separate. I only pass `DataSet` from the form.

**Form**

```
private DataSet AdreseDataSet;

public void PopulateAdressTabWithAdresses()
{
    this.AdreseDataSet = PartnerRepository.Instance.ListaAdresaDataSet(_selectedPartnerID);

    this._adreseBindingSource.DataSource = this.AdreseDataSet.Tables[0];
    this.adresBindingNavigator1.BindingSource = this._adreseBindingSource;
    this.adreseDataGridView.DataSource = this._adreseBindingSource;
}


private void adreseDataGridView_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        if (this.AdreseDataSet.GetChanges() != null)
        {
            PartnerRepository.Instance.SaveChanges(this.AdreseDataSet);
        }
    }
}
```

**Data**

```
    public DataSet ListaAdresaDataSet(int id)
    {
        using (conn = new MySqlConnection(DB.connString))
        {
            conn.Open();

            this.adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT id, partner_id, adresa, broj, mesto, posta, primarna FROM partneri_adrese  WHERE partner_id = @partner_id;", conn);
            this.adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("partner_id", id.ToString());
            this.ds = new DataSet();
            this.adapter.Fill(this.ds);
        }

        return this.ds;
    }

   public void SaveChanges(DataSet dst)
    {
        this.ds = dst;

        try
        {
            DataSet changes = this.ds.GetChanges();

            if (changes != null)
            {

                this.builder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(adapter);

                int updatedRows = this.adapter.Update(changes);

                MessageBox.Show("Database has been updated successfully: " + updatedRows + " Modified row(s) ", "Success");

                this.ds.AcceptChanges();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Nothing to save", "No changes");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An error occurred updating the database: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            this.ds.RejectChanges();
        }

    }
```

**Database**

```
ID  |  partner_id   |  adresa  | mesto | posta 
----------------------------------------------------
1   |  (null)       | test     | test  | 123
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe you could explain where you expect this `partner_id` value to come from. We can't tell you why what you're doing isn't working if we don't know what you're doing. Are you just assuming that it will be populated automatically because you used that as a filter in the original query? If so, why would you think that? Neither your grid nor your `DataTable` know anything about that query and, even if they did, why would they automatically use the same value? Either enter the value explicitly yourself or make it the default value for that `DataColumn`.

Comment: I have form where `dgv` shows all partners. On row double click i open new form where i pas partner id and load all data for partner by id. Also addresses was loaded by that `id`. When new row is added in dgv i need to save that address for that partner. In my case i dont know where to pass that default value (partner_id). I was hoping that the adapter update would recognize itself from the `WHERE` clause, but it didn't.

Comment: It doesn't, and why would it? `WHERE` clauses can be as complex as you like so what rules would they use? Even if they were able to identify that one foreign key value, how would they know that any new records added should use the same value? It's not a given that that's what you'd want. You can handle an appropriate event and set the value explicitly or you can set the `DefaultValue` of that `DataColumn` and that value will be used automatically for every new row.

Comment: `DefaultValue` is for `DataTable` in my case is `DataSet`

Comment: Really!? What exactly do you think `this.AdreseDataSet.Tables[0]` is? You should do a bit of reading on what a `DataSet` actually is.

Comment: I don't like your tone of voice. Please!